# stream live video from IP Cams in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, rtsp, rtp, ip-camera, mpeg-4

I have to develop plug-in module which will allow us to stream live video from IP Cams if the IP of the cameras are available. The format and encoding for the same is: MPEG4 RTSP/RTP but I dont know from where to start. I have search in many site, unable to find any thing related. while browsing the Apples doc's, I found `AVFoundation` is used to stream live video from IP Cam's.

**UPDATE**
I found [this](https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone) from GITHUB but dont know How to implement it in my App.

Please help me by sample code or related app and suggest me to overcome this. thanks in Advance.

Comment: solved ? I face the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding some references for you - let me know if that helps.

[Elsewhere people have said](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2019019) that iPhone doesn't support native RTSP.

However, one possible thing that works (since there many folks who are working in SO on this), is to use live HTTP.

Some resources from -
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-07

[MPEG-TS Segments HTTP Live Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635666/mpeg-ts-segments-http-live-streaming/8644496#8644496)

Answer (score 0):

I've migrated ffmpeg & live555 to iOS, and has an app to accept MPEG4/H264 video stream from the IPcam.

Comment: Can you tell me how we can broadcast live video from ios device to a server?

Comment: @ciphor can you share how to do it?